# Units and Primes in a Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is it true that units in a ring (maybe involves in quaternions) have norm of 1?
(norm of 1 does not imply that it is a unit, right?)
What about the statement that the number is prime if and only if it has prime norm?
Can we derive second statement 2 from the first one?

Comment: Not all rings have norms on them.

Comment: If a ring does have norms, is it true?

Comment: If it's a Euclidean norm? Yes.

Comment: Can you give me a hint on how to prove it?

Comment: The norm of an ideal is the index of the ideal it generates. If an ideal has index 1, it is the whole ring, hence is generated by a unit.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if the guesswork involved in figuring out what you're asking involves more brainpower than actually answering the question, then you are not being clear enough. Please clarify what kind of rings, and what kind of "norms," you are speaking about. The quaternions are a division ring so we'd hardly speak of primes, unless we're restricting to $\Bbb Z\langle i,j,k\rangle$ or somesuch. And the absolute value "norms" are not exactly the same as the product-of-conjugates "norms" from galois theory / algebraic number theory.